# How can I use Android.App.Application and Xamarin.Forms.Application in the same class?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I get an error message because I have the following two lines of code in the same class:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Android.App;
```

> Error CS0104: 'Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'Android.App.Application' and 'Xamarin.Forms.Application'

```
 if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
   deviceID = Settings.Secure.GetString(Application.Context.ContentResolver, Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
```

How can I use Android.App to execute the code? I need the deviceID.
I can not remove "using Xamarin.Forms;" because I use it in the class.

Comment: Fully qualify it `Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver` or create an alias: `using AApp = Android.App;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign an alias to a namespace

```
using xf = Xamarin.Forms;
using aa = Android.App;

...

aa.Application.Context.ContentResolver...
```

or you can just use the fully qualified namespace in your code

```
Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver...
```

or use the `global` keyword if your project namespace conflicts with another namespace

```
global::Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver...
```

Comment: Thanks, the first option works. The second option is not working, I get another error message when I use Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver: Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'App' does not exist in the namespace 'Myproject.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: that is because it cannot distinguish between MyProject.Android and the base Android namespace.  Generally it's a good idea to NOT use "Android" in your project name to avoid this.  But you can workaround it by using the global keyword - see my edit